# Select first N rows of Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cql

As stated in this [doc](http://www.slideshare.net/jericevans/cql20) to select a range of rows i have to write this:

```
select first 100 col1..colN from table;
```

but when I launch this on ***cql shell*** I get this error:

```
<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:13 no viable alternative at input '100' (select [first] 100...)">
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to the [Docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html#Filteringrows), key word first is to limit the number of Columnns, not rows

to limit the number of rows , you must just keyword limit.

```
select col1..colN from table  limit 100;
```

the default limit is 10000

Comment: Can you please assist ,If I want to retrieve result from 11th to 20th record only. How can I achieve this in CQL.

Comment: I down voted by mistake obviously and now it is locked. Sorry.